# Error en la conexion de base de datos mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una conexion de base de datos que no me funciona con php y mysql usando PDO

```
<?php

class DWESBaseDatos {

    private $conexion = null;
    private $sentencia = null;
    private $executed = false;

    private static $instanciaUnica = null;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function obtenerInstancia() {
        if (self::$instanciaUnica == null)
        {
          self::$instanciaUnica = new DWESBaseDatos();
        }

        return self::$instanciaUnica;
    }

    function inicializa(
        $basedatos = 'prueba_php',
        $usuario  = 'root',
        $pass     = 'Teamokarina1.',
        $motor    = 'mysql',
        $serverIp = 'localhost',
        $charset  = 'utf8mb4',
        $options  = null
    ) {
        if($motor != "sqlite") {
          $cadenaConexion = "$motor:host=$serverIp;dbname=$basedatos;charset=$charset";
        } else {
          $cadenaConexion = "$motor:$basedatos";
        }

        if($options == null){
            $options = [
              PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // La preparación de las consultas no es simulada
                                                     // más lento pero más seguro
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // Cuando se produce un error
                                                                      // salta una excepción
              PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, // Cuando traemos datos lo hacemos como array asociativo
            ];
        }

        try {
          if($motor != "sqlite") {
            $this->conexion = new PDO($cadenaConexion, $usuario, $pass, $options);
          } else {
            $this->conexion = new PDO($cadenaConexion, null, null, $options);
          }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          error_log($e->getMessage());
          exit($e);
        }
    }

    /*
      Permite ejecutar una consulta preparada con parámetros posicionales.
        Parámetros
          1º SQL
          2º ... parámetros o array con parámetros
    */
    function ejecuta(string $sql, ...$parametros) {
        $this->sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

        if($parametros == null){
            $this->executed = $this->sentencia->execute();
            return;
        }

        if($parametros != null && is_array($parametros[0])) {
            $parametros = $parametros[0]; // Si nos pasan un array lo usamos como parámetro
        }

        $this->executed = $this->sentencia->execute($parametros);
    }

    function obtenDatos(){
        return $this->sentencia->fetchAll();
    }

    function getLastId(){
        return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
    }

    function getExecuted(){
        return $this->executed;
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->conexion = null;
    }
}
?>
```

En otro archivo tengo lo siguiente

```
$db = DWESBaseDatos::obtenerInstancia();
$db->inicializa($config['db_file'], null, null, $config['db_engine']);
```

Obtengo un error con mi conexion a la base de datos local

**PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/PHPprueba/src/DWESBaseDatos.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/PHPprueba/src/DWESBaseDatos.php(50): PDO->__construct() #1 /var/www/html/PHPprueba/src/db.php(4): DWESBaseDatos->inicializa() #2 /var/www/html/PHPprueba/public/enrutador.php(12): require_once('/var/www/html/P...') #3 {main}**

Agradeceria su apoyo.

Comment: Deberías hacer una búsqueda sencilla en google antes de preguntar (https://www.google.com/search?q=PDOException%3A+could+not+find+driver+in) Revisa esto [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver ). Si ya lo has hecho  indicanos que pruebas hiciste y con que resultado. No olvides consultar la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) antes de preguntar.

Comment: *`PDOException: could not find driver`* suele ocurrir cuando no tienes instalado/activado el controlador PDO en tu entorno PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por que no le estas pasando valor de usuario y contraseña, según lo que estas haciendo es lo siguiente:

Al pasarle estos valores a la función inicializa

```
$db->inicializa($config['db_file'], null, null, $config['db_engine']);
```

Lo que estas haciendo es que el script entienda lo siguiente:

```
$basedatos = {valorDe`$config['db_file']`},
$usuario  = null,
$pass     = null,
$motor    = {valorDe`$config['db_engine']`},
$serverIp = 'localhost',
$charset  = 'utf8mb4',
$options  = null
```

No se si es posible, pero creo que no se permite conexiones con usuario y contraseña null. Al final al pasarle los valores null sobrescribes los valores por defecto.

Un saludo

Comment: Entiendo, ya repare ese error ahora no da error pero me responde un 302